# Retrieve files from a folder in S3 in Android

Tags: android, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I am using the following code to retrieve file from S3 folder. I am receiving an error "open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)". Since I have folders in bucket the summary.getKey() will result in format folder_name/file_name. Any help will be much appreciated.

List s3ObjList = objectListing.getObjectSummaries();

```
    for (S3ObjectSummary summary : s3ObjList) {
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + summary.getKey());
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdirs();
        }
        TransferObserver observer = transferUtility.download("bucket_name", summary.getKey(), file);

    }
```

Comment: is 'if' condition executed?

Comment: Yes each new file it is executed

Comment: You are creating new directory using file.mkdirs()  each time. Just create a directory manually and place files into it and remove the if conditions and run code

Comment: Its strange the same code is working in device but not working in emulator.

Comment: I got it fixed. Problem was with /sdcard/ folder missing in emulator. When I changed it to internal storage it worked. Reason for it to work in mobile was due to the fact that there was no memory card in the phone. I guess since memory card was not present it targeted internal memory and worked. Thank you Rai for the support